# Dynamic input variables based on selected timeframe period selected

Tags: pine-script

I want to be able to display the 50 Day EMA no matter what timeframe period is selected. For example, for Daily timeframe, the EMA input would be 50 to display 50 day EMA and for a custom 12-hour timeframe the input would be 100 in order to display the 50 day. I want to define the timeframes that I am interested in and select a default variable for any other timeframe not defined. I only care about specific timeframes so I don't mind entering these manually.

This is what I tried, but didn't work. The reason I entered it as an input box as well, is to see the change here and modify if I want to.

```
//@version=4
testingnew = timeframe.period

if testingnew == "240"
    set_to=60
else
    if testingnew == "W"
        set_to=2
    else
        set_to=20

// Input variables
len=input(set_to,title="test")
```

Comment: Have you looked at the security() function?

Comment: the security() function is when you are trying to plot something alternate against your current selected security.

The timeframe.period is listing the specific text that I'm looking for, the problem is arising from the:

len=input(set_to,title="test"

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it was simple, I have to adjust it after the initial definition.

```
//@version=4
study("study")
testingnew = timeframe.period
len=input(14,title="test")
if testingnew == "240"
    set_to=60   
else
    if testingnew == "W"
        set_to=2
    else
        set_to=20
// Input variables len:=set_to
```

It will however disable the input functionality as the code is setting the variable. Will probably add a boolean input that states to disable this check so to allow the input box to function in case I want to change my variable again.